# Solr : How to retrieve all documents of a group if one of the group match the query?

Tags: search, solr

I'm using **Solr 8.4**.
I have a huge database with many documents. 
Those documents have a type and there are a lot of different types as well.
For 100 documents, there is about 80 different types.
If I search for a document, grouping by type, SOLR returns correctly documents that matched the query and grouped by types.

I would like SOLR to include ALL documents related to the type returned. I'm not asking to return ALL documents, but just the ones for which the types is returned, because there was a match with one of the document in the same group.

Let's take an example

```
> GroupA - Dog
> GroupA - Cat
> GroupA - Dogger
> GroupB - Dog
> GroupB - Dogly
> GroupC - Bear
```

If I search "Dog". Solr returns this

```
> GroupA
>> Dog
>> Dogger
> GroupB
>> Dog
>> Dogly
```

But I would like this

```
> GroupA
>> Dog
>> Dogger
>> Cat
> GroupB
>> Dog
>> Dogly
```

So **Cat** is also included. But **Bear** stays well excluded.

Comment: Any reason why group.limit doesn't work? `group.limit`: Specifies the number of results to return for each group. The default value is 1.

Comment: I currently have group.limit to 10. Anyway this would limit the matches inside the group. In this case, I would like to include non-matches of the group as well.

Comment: I think you're going to have to do two queries in that case - one to fetch the groups and one to fetch the documents.

Comment: Yes, that's my plan B, but this will lower the performances :(

Comment: You might be able to [express it as a streaming expression](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/streaming-expressions.html) - not sure about the performance in that case. I don't have the time right not to try to create an example, but might have some time on Monday.